# SlidingTabLayout with active tab locked to center

Tags: android

I was trying to modify the SlidingTabLayout from Google IO app so that the active tab is always locked to the middle like in the latest Google Play Newsstand and Foursquare versions. How would I got about implementing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modified the SlidingTabLayout so that the HorizontalScrollView that contains the tabs adjusts its padding based on the ViewPager's scroll offset. It took me 3 days to create an acceptable result and I hope it helps you too! If you have any questions and/or improvements, please comment!

[image]

SlidingTabLayout.java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.animation.LayoutTransition;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * To be used with ViewPager to provide a tab indicator component which give constant feedback as to
 * the user's scroll progress.
 * <p/>
 * To use the component, simply add it to your view hierarchy. Then in your
 * {@link android.app.Activity} or {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} call
 * {@link #setViewPager(ViewPager)} providing it the ViewPager this layout is being used for.
 * <p/>
 * The colors can be customized in two ways. The first and simplest is to provide an array of colors
 * via {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)}. The
 * alternative is via the {@link TabColorizer} interface which provides you complete control over
 * which color is used for any individual position.
 * <p/>
 * The views used as tabs can be customized by calling {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)},
 * providing the layout ID of your custom layout.
 */
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {
    /**
     * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
     * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
     */
    public interface TabColorizer {

        /**
         * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
         */
        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    }

    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;
    private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        //mTabStrip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Set spacer tab widths
                View firstTab = mTabStrip.getChildAt(0);
                int firstTabPadding = (getWidth() - mTabStrip.getChildAt(1).getMeasuredWidth()) / 2;
                firstTab.setPadding(firstTabPadding, firstTab.getPaddingTop(), firstTab.getPaddingRight(), firstTab.getPaddingBottom());

                View lastTab = mTabStrip.getChildAt(mTabStrip.getChildCount() - 1);
                int lastTabPadding = (getWidth() - mTabStrip.getChildAt(mTabStrip.getChildCount() - 2).getMeasuredWidth()) / 4;
                lastTab.setPadding(lastTabPadding, 0, lastTabPadding, 0);


                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                else
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
     * <p/>
     * If you only require simple customisation then you can use
     * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve
     * similar effects.
     */
    public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
        mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
     * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
     */
    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
     * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
     *
     * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
     */
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
     *
     * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
     * @param textViewId  id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
     */
    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
        mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
     * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
     */
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
            populateTabStrip();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
     * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
     */
    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    private void populateTabStrip() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
            }

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }

            if (mDistributeEvenly) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
            }

            tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
            String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
            if (desc != null) {
                tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
            }

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                tabView.setSelected(true);
            }
        }

        // First spacer tab
        TextView firstTab = new TextView(getContext());
        mTabStrip.addView(firstTab, 0);

        // Last spacer tab
        TextView lastTab = new TextView(getContext());
        mTabStrip.addView(lastTab);
    }

    public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
        mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
    }

    private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
            return;
        }

        if (positionOffset == -1) {// Not manual scroll. Do not animate. Just cut to tab and center.
            if (tabIndex == 1)
                positionOffset = 0;
            else
                positionOffset = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex).getWidth() / 2 + mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex + 1).getWidth() / 2;
        }

        if (tabIndex == 1) // if tab number one, no need to calculate previously scrolled X
            scrollTo(positionOffset, 0);
        else { // If tab number is greater than 1, we need to calculate previously scrolled X
            int previouslyScrolledX = 0;

            // Simulate previously scrolled X by summing half of each of the previous tabs' width.
            // Use 2 tabs per loop for correct simulation.
            for (int i = 1; i < tabIndex; i++) {
                previouslyScrolledX += mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).getWidth() / 2;
                previouslyScrolledX += mTabStrip.getChildAt(i + 1).getWidth() / 2;
            }

            scrollTo(previouslyScrolledX + positionOffset, 0);
        }
    }

    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                return;
            }

            position++; // Offset position by 1 to make up for left blank tab

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            // Adding half of current tab's width & half of next tab's width and scrolling by that width will center next tab
            int offsetToCenterNextTab = (mTabStrip.getChildAt(position).getWidth() / 2) + (mTabStrip.getChildAt(position + 1).getWidth() / 2);

            scrollToTab(position, Math.round(offsetToCenterNextTab * positionOffset));

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, -1);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position + 1 == i);
            }
            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View selectedView) {
            View lastSelectedView = null;
            int selectedViewIndex = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount() - 1; i++) {
                View currentViewInLoop = mTabStrip.getChildAt(i);
                if (currentViewInLoop.isSelected()) {
                    lastSelectedView = currentViewInLoop;
                }

                if (selectedView == currentViewInLoop) {
                    selectedViewIndex = i - 1;
                }

                if (lastSelectedView != null && selectedViewIndex != 0)
                    break;
            }

            Rect tabContainerRect = new Rect();
            Rect lastSelectedTabRect = new Rect();

            getDrawingRect(tabContainerRect);
            lastSelectedView.getHitRect(lastSelectedTabRect);

            if (Rect.intersects(tabContainerRect, lastSelectedTabRect))
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedViewIndex);
            else
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedViewIndex, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but I have a problem here as if I put a custom layout for a strip with imageview and textview, when I create the layout for the first time it is kinda stuck, but gets okay after first swipe. Could u look into that ?

Comment: @XOOLOOO, I've updated the code with the latest version that I'm currently using. It scrolls perfectly and has better performance. Please test it. The only bug is when I rotate the screen, the tabs are not centered until you scroll them. I'll have to look into it when I'm free.

Comment: It's not centered when using custom tab view , and tabs will disappear.

Comment: `SlidingTabStrip` is not included ?